# unable to install ubuntu/ or linux distribution from usb

Tags: 12.04, installation, boot, live-usb

I assembled a new computer and first installed windows 8.

When I then try to install Ubuntu 12.04 I can see ubuntu loading and I reach upto a point where I can move the mouse pointer and I can see ubuntu logo, but nothing more happens and the machine freezes.

Points to consider:

- The computer is working with windows 8.
- I have previously installed Ubuntu on my system but now I cannot install.
- I tried with different versions of Ubuntu and also Linux mint.
- Because my old Ubuntu (12.04) stopped working after I tried to install ATI
  graphics drivers. so I deleted my old Ubuntu partition and I am trying to
  install a new one.
- The bootable USB stick is working fine as I tried it on my friends laptop and it loaded a live session quickly.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

I think ubuntu not working with window 8,, but I install ubuntu with window 7 and work properly,, but fully formatted windows 7  T.T

i'm using pendrive to install ubuntu.

maybe your RAM is to low and make your system  freeze, minimum RAM requirement for window 8 is 2GB.. or maybe your system is 64bit but you installing 32bit..

Comment: my ram is 6gb and i am trying to install 64bit ubuntu on my lap. i have previosly installed abuntu alongside same installation of windows 8. but for some reason it is not now working.